# XAML DataGridTextColumn: display an empty cell when condition is false

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a Collection of Article and some of them have a price and others don't.

When a price is available I want my datagrid to display it even if it's 0.

When a price is not possible on the article the default value is 0 and I don't want it to appear in the datagrid and the cell should be in readonly.

This is what I tried:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="PU" Binding="{Binding PU, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Mesurage.HasPrice}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Text" Value="{Binding PU, StringFormat=0;;#, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

I used a StringFormat to hide the 0 but it still show it in my grid. Aslo the IsReadOnly property could not be modified in the trigger so I use the Focusable property instead.

Is there a way to achieve the wanted result in XAML only? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try set `IsEnabled` to `false` to disable input

also set `Foreground` to `Transparent`: the `0` value will be there but not visible

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Mesurage.HasPrice}" Value="False">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. I did try to set the ForeGround to White But I could see the value when the row was selected. I didn't know it could take Transparent has value.

Comment: Foreground is a property of type `Brush`. It can take "Transparent", "Red", "Green", "Blue" strings, etc and convert them to `SolidColorBrush`. It can take other types of brushes, `LinearGradientBrush`. There is also a special `{x:Null}` value (`null` equivalent in xaml). Transparent/x:Null are often used to hide elements

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.I tried to upvote your answer but I don't have enought reputation to do it.